# Save an object and immediately retrieve it back

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

I want to save an object, and then retrieve it back from the database, but somehow the saving works, but the retrieving returns null.

```
public static Work startWork(Work work)
{
   Context.context.Work.AddObject(work);
   Context.context.SaveChanges();
   Work result = (from r in Context.context.Work
                  where r.ReceiptID == work.ReceiptID && r.begin == work.begin
                  select r).FirstOrDefault();
   return result;
}
```

So I pass a work instance which already has its `begin` and `ReceiptID` set so that I can retrieve it, but it just returns null.

Comment: Are there triggers on the database tables that might alter one of those values?

Comment: Have you tried `Context.context.RefreshObject(work, RefreshMode.StoreWins)`?

Comment: What is your `ReceiptID` - is that an identity column in SQL Server by any chance? If so: when you **add** an object and then save it, a new `ReceiptID` might be created when the row is actually stored - so trying to retrieve that newly inserted row with the "old" `ReceiptID` won't return anything.....

Comment: `ReceiptID` is the foreign key that points to a `Receipt` object

Comment: @jessehouwing calling refresh worked, post it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating the object you can call the [`ObjectContext.Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to have EntityFramework grab the latest data for the object from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Work newWork = Context.context.Work.Add(work);
```

This will give you access to the newly created object. marc_s had the right idea. The `work` object is not getting assigned a `ReceiptID` because it represents the object you submitted to the function, not the object you saved to the Db.

Comment: `ReceiptID` is the foreign key that points to a `Receipt` object, and there is no "Add" method in `Context.context.Work`

Comment: If there is now way to make this work wit entity manager, then maybe i should write a stored procedure in my database server and import it into my app, what do you think?